# nginx rewrite url issue

Tags: nginx, regex

Current rewrite URL :

```
rewrite ^/link/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$   /link.php?one=$1&two=$2&three=$3 last;
```

What I need is solution so three link samples work:

1) `/link/one/`

2) `/link/one/two/`

3) `/link/one/two/three/`

What shoulnd't work :

```
/link/one

/link/one/two

/link/one/two/three
```

Aditional question : would it be possible for each link to link to separate script?

Example

`/link/one/` > script1.php

`/link/one/two/` > script2.php

`/link/one/two/three/` > script3.php

I am not looking for static links,  "one", "two" and "three" will be dynamic inputs.

Comment: What is your former question exactly ?

Comment: Yes, it is not really clear what your are asking...What is the actual URL you got and what do you want at the end ?

Comment: Well i want one main url 
/link/title/
but same link with title can (but don't need to) have aditional parameters, like /link/title/date/  /link/title/date/comment/. Hopefully that makes more sense

Comment: @Ivan Really not more clear for me...